# MongoDB/Mongoose Schema for Accounts with Multiple Users

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I'm looking for some suggestions on a MongoDB schema I'm thinking of. I would love to get some comments and possible corrections. This will be for a login system where there are accounts but each account can have multiple users/administrators. Each user will have his/her own login but I'm thinking of embedding everything into the Account document. There won't be more than 10 users per account (I'm thinking that if there had to be a 100 users, performance would still not be impacted). Here is what a typical document could look like.

```
{
    id: ObjectId(),
    modified: date,
    users: {
        user@domain.com:{
            password: hash
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I can create sub documents like that for users and if it would be efficient to get the account information by looking up the user's email and password.

Still reading up on schema design but any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: If you store a username as a field name, you won't be able to do searches. Do: `users: [ { login: "user@example.com", pwd: "hash" }]`. Then, you could index on `users.login` for quick lookup. But, I'm not sure that I'd store everything in a single document anyway, unless there was some benefit that I'm missing ...

Comment: the benefit here is that I need to get the account information when a user logs in so the query is searching for 1 document. would you still recommend splitting them up into separate collections?

Comment: If that's how yore using it, makes sense as one doc.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer embedding instead of linking for such this cases. Your scenario is very suitable for embedding. I would create 2 models. One of them is **Account**, another is **User**. The reason of defining User model separately is defining your user models behavior. Let say, you are adding a user to specified account with an registration form. When you post form, you can directly cast form body post values to User model and embed it to Account model. I have created models like;

```
Account = new Schema({
    users:{
        type:[User],
        required:true
    },
    modified:{
        type:String,
        required:false
    }
});

User = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});
```

You can also have a look at gist [here](https://gist.github.com/cubuzoa/8100441) for example definition.

Comment: This does not work well if a user is allowed to belong to multiple accounts so I'm sticking with linking for now.

Comment: You can embed user into several accounts

Comment: yes but if any info about the user changes, every account needs to be updated.